# HTML JavaScript - div elements working differently between Chrome and Safari/Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing an HTML website with embedded YouTube videos controlled by a JavaScript script.

I have three videos and they are all working fine on Chrome but not on Safari and Firefox.

The weirdest thing is that I've embedded them in the same way, both on Safari and Firefox the first video is working fine but when the other two start playing, you can only hear audio.

You can visit the website here:
https://matteo-stable-web-server.herokuapp.com/

From desktop on a full screen, if you click the arrow at the bottom on the right you'll see the first video playing.
If you click again you'll see the second video on Chrome but you'll only hear the audio on Safari and Firefox.

While inspecting the page I noticed that the iFrame elements generated by YouTube API inside the div elements have some differences with dimensions. It seems like the video is playing but it is somewhere else. But this is only a feeling of mine (see image below).

[image: Inspection Comparison - Working vs Not working]

This is the HTML (class="firstVideo" is what we are looking for)

```
<body >
        <nav role="navigation">
            <div id="menuToggle">

                <input type="checkbox" />

                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>

                <ul id="menu">
                    <a href="./index.html"><li>Home</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Come funziona</li></a>
                    <a href="./faq.html"><li>FAQ</li></a>
                    <a href="./blog.html"><li>Blog</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Contatti</li></a>
                    <a href="./pdf/RegolamentoFlav.pdf" target="_blank"><li>Regolamento</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Ringraziamenti</li></a>
                </ul>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div id="rotateRect" class="redRect rotateRectStart hideXS"></div>



        <div id="nav">
            <div id="leftArrow"><img src="img/arrow_right.png" alt="flav website controls"></div>
            <div id="rightArrow"><img src="img/arrow_right.png" alt="flav website controls"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="containerTop">
        <div id="backImg">
            <div class="landscapeImg"></div>
            <div class="firstImg"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="leftContainer">
            <div class="splashLeft">
                <img class="logoHome" src="img/logo_flav.svg" alt="flav app"><br>
                <h5>Ciò che vuoi, dove vuoi, quando vuoi.</h5>
                <h1>Richiedi, Offri…<br>GUADAGNA!</h1>
                <h2>CON FLAV ESSERE DISPONIBILI RIPAGA. SEMPRE.</h2>
                <a href="#"><img class="badge" src="img/app-store-badge.png" alt="download on the app store"></a>
                <a href="#"><img class="badge" src="img/google-play-badge.png" alt="download on the google play store"></a>
                <br><br>
                <h6>CONTACT & FOLLOW US ON:</h6>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/app.FLAV.it/"><img class="socialIcon" src="img/facebook.png" alt="flav facebook fanpage"></a>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/flav.it/"><img class="socialIcon" src="img/instagram.png" alt="flav instagram fanpage"></a>
                <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC5MeGaeI9boibIcUq0X4FXg"><img class="socialIcon" src="img/youtube.png" alt="flav youtube channel"></a>
                <a href="mailto:info@flav.it?Subject=Information"><img class="socialIcon" src="img/mail.png" alt="flav mail"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="rightContainer">
            <img class="iphoneSplash" src="img/iphoneSplash.png" alt="flav, ciò che vuoi quando vuoi dove vuoi">
        </div>

        <div id="firstLeftPart">
            <img class="redLogo hideXS" src="img/logoRed.svg" alt="flav, ciò che vuoi quando vuoi dove vuoi"><br>
            <div class="numberSect01">N° <span class="bigNum">01</span></div>
            <h2 id="titleNumbFirst" class="titlePart01"><span class="numb hideXS">| 03</span><br>Fai la tua richiesta</h2>
            <br>
            <span class="subTitle">Chiedi ciò di cui hai bisogno.</span><br>
            <p>
              Ti serve qualcosa o hai bisogno di una mano?<br>Pubblica la tua richiesta scegliendo tra beni e servizi, seleziona la categoria, stabilisci luogo e ora.<br>Ricevi le risposte di utenti e professionisti direttamente nella App <br>e scegli l’utente che fa per te con l’offerta più conveniente.<br><br>Trovare ciò di cui hai bisogno non è mai stato cosi facile!<br><span class="downloadIt">Scarica FLAV!</span><br>       
            </p>

        </div>

        <div id="iphoneFirst">
            <img class="whiteIphone"  src="img/iphoneFirstPart.png" alt="flav, ciò che vuoi quando vuoi dove vuoi">
            <div class="firstVideo" id="videoNumberOne"></div>
            <a class="mLeft hideXS" href="#"><img class="badge" src="img/app-store-badge.png" alt="download on the app store"></a>
            <a class="hideXS" href="#"><img class="badge" src="img/google-play-badge.png" alt="download on the google play store"></a>
        </div>

        <div id="secondRightPart">
            <img class="redLogo hideXS" src="img/logo_flav.svg" alt="flav, ciò che vuoi quando vuoi dove vuoi"><br>
            <div class="numberSect01">N° <span class="bigNum">02</span></div>
            <h2 id="titleNumbFirst" class="titlePart01"><span class="numb hideXS">| 03</span><br>FAI IL TUO PREZZO</h2>
            <br>
            <span class="subTitle">Renditi disponibile.</span><br>
            <p>
              Vuoi rispondere a una richiesta? <br><br>Consulta le richieste della community.<br>Apri la mappa, scopri di cosa hanno bisogno le persone intorno a te<br>e fai il tuo prezzo.<br><br>Guadagnare non è mai stato cosi semplice!<br><span class="downloadIt">Scarica FLAV!</span><br>        
            </p>

        </div>

        <div id="iphoneSecond">
            <img class="whiteIphone" src="img/iphoneFirstPart.png" alt="flav, ciò che vuoi quando vuoi dove vuoi">
                <div class="firstVideo" id="videoNumberTwo"></div>
            <a class="mLeft hideXS" href="#"><img class="badge" src="img/app-store-badge.png" alt="download on the app store"></a>
            <a class="hideXS" href="#"><img class="badge" src="img/google-play-badge.png" alt="download on the google play store"></a>
        </div>

        <div id="thirdLeftPart">
            <img class="redLogo hideXS" src="img/logoRed.svg" alt="flav, ciò che vuoi quando vuoi dove vuoi"><br>
            <div class="numberSect01">N° <span class="bigNum">03</span></div>
            <h2 id="titleNumbFirst" class="titlePart01"><span class="numb hideXS">| 03</span><br>FAI LA TUA OFFERTA</h2>
            <br>
            <span class="subTitle">Vendi, offri e guadagna.</span><br>
            <p>
              Vuoi vendere qualcosa? Vuoi incrementare la tua visibilità e i tuoi guadagni? <br><br>Pubblica la tua offerta di beni o servizi,<br> ricevi le risposte degli utenti e concorda ogni dettaglio in chat.<br> In modo facile e gratuito.<br>La chiave del successo è essere ovunque!<br><span class="downloadIt">Scarica FLAV!</span><br>       
            </p>

        </div>

        <div id="iphoneThird">
            <img class="whiteIphone" src="img/iphoneFirstPart.png" alt="flav, ciò che vuoi quando vuoi dove vuoi">
            <div class="firstVideo" id="videoNumberThree"></div>
            </video>
            <a class="mLeft hideXS" href="#"><img class="badge" src="img/app-store-badge.png" alt="download on the app store"></a>
            <a class="hideXS" href="#"><img class="badge" src="img/google-play-badge.png" alt="download on the google play store"></a>

        </div>

        <div class="hideXL">
            <a href="#"><img class="badge" src="img/app-store-badge.png" alt="download on the app store"></a>
            <a href="#"><img class="badge" src="img/google-play-badge.png" alt="download on the google play store"></a>
            <br><br>
            <h6>CONTACT & FOLLOW US ON:</h6>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/app.FLAV.it/"><img class="socialIcon" src="img/facebook.png" alt="flav facebook fanpage"></a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/flav.it/"><img class="socialIcon" src="img/instagram.png" alt="flav instagram fanpage"></a>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC5MeGaeI9boibIcUq0X4FXg"><img class="socialIcon" src="img/youtube.png" alt="flav youtube channel"></a>
            <a href="mailto:info@flav.it?Subject=Information"><img class="socialIcon" src="img/mail.png" alt="flav mail"></a>
        </div>
        </div>



        <script src="js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/base.js"></script>
    </body>
```

This is the JavaScript

```
var countSlide = 0;

//YOUTUBE START
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player1;
var player2;
var player3;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player1 = new YT.Player('videoNumberOne', {
       videoId: 'Kifn_WVGReM',
        events: {
          'onReady': onPlayerReady
        }
    });

    player2 = new YT.Player('videoNumberTwo', {
        videoId: 'wa7aa5-GxW8',
        events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady
        }
    });

    player3 = new YT.Player('videoNumberThree', {
        videoId: 'YCIOKI0ZSTM',
        events: {
          'onReady': onPlayerReady
        }
    });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.setVolume(50);
    //event.target.pauseVideo();
}

//YOUTUBE END

// $( document ).ready(function() {      

// });

function pauseAndReset(video) {
    video.pauseVideo();
    video.seekTo(0);
}

//SLIDE ROUTINE

$("#rightArrow").click(function(){
    if (countSlide < 3) {
        countSlide++;
    }

    if (countSlide == 1){
        toBottom();

        player1.playVideo();
    }
    else if (countSlide == 2) {
        toTop();

        pauseAndReset(player1);
        player2.playVideo();
    }
    else if (countSlide == 3) {
        setTimeout(toSndBottom,25);
        setTimeout(toTop,50);
        setTimeout(toSndBottom,70);

        pauseAndReset(player2);
        player3.playVideo();
    }
    else if (countSlide >= 3) {
        //Go Back to Homepage
    }     
});

$("#leftArrow").click(function(){
    if (countSlide > 0) {
        countSlide--;
    }

    if (countSlide == 0){
        toStart();
        pauseAndReset(player1);
    }
    else if (countSlide == 1) {
        toBottom();
        pauseAndReset(player2);
        player1.playVideo();
    }
    else if (countSlide == 2) {
        toSndTop();
        pauseAndReset(player3);
        player2.playVideo();
    }
});
//SLIDE ROUTINE ENDS

$(".redLogo").click(function(){
    toStart();
    countSlide = 0;

    $("#firstLeftPart").css("marginLeft", "-105%");
    $("#iphoneFirst").css("marginLeft", "152%");

    $("#secondRightPart").css("marginLeft", "-105%");
    $("#iphoneSecond").css("marginLeft", "152%");

    $("#thirdLeftPart").css("marginLeft", "-105%");
    $("#iphoneThird").css("marginLeft", "152%"); 
});



function toStart () {
    $("#rotateRect").addClass('rotateRectStart');
    $("#rotateRect").removeClass('rotateRectBottom');
    $("#rotateRect").removeClass('rotateRectTop');
    $(".iphoneSplash").css("marginLeft", "0%");
    $(".splashLeft").css("marginLeft", "0%");
    $(".landscapeImg").fadeIn('fast');
    $(".firstImg").fadeOut('slow');

    $("#firstLeftPart").css("marginLeft", "-105%");
    $("#iphoneFirst").css("marginLeft", "152%");

}

function toTop () {
    $("#rotateRect").removeClass('rotateRectStart');
    $("#rotateRect").removeClass('rotateRectBottom');    

    $("#rotateRect").addClass('rotateRectTop');

    $("#firstLeftPart").css("marginLeft", "-105%");
    $("#iphoneFirst").css("marginLeft", "152%");

    $("#secondRightPart").css("marginLeft", "5%");
    $("#iphoneSecond").css("marginLeft", "52%");  
}

function toBottom () {
    $("#rotateRect").removeClass('rotateRectStart');
    $("#rotateRect").removeClass('rotateRectTop');
    $("#rotateRect").addClass('rotateRectBottom');

    $(".iphoneSplash").css("marginLeft", "200%");    
    $(".splashLeft").css("marginLeft", "-200%");

    $(".landscapeImg").fadeOut('fast');
    $(".firstImg").fadeIn('slow');

    $("#firstLeftPart").css("marginLeft", "5%");
    $("#iphoneFirst").css("marginLeft", "52%");

    $("#secondRightPart").css("marginLeft", "-105%");
    $("#iphoneSecond").css("marginLeft", "152%"); 
}

function toSndBottom () {

    $("#rotateRect").removeClass('rotateRectTop');
    $("#rotateRect").addClass('rotateRectBottom');

    $("#thirdLeftPart").css("marginLeft", "5%");
    $("#iphoneThird").css("marginLeft", "52%");  

    $("#secondRightPart").css("marginLeft", "-105%");
    $("#iphoneSecond").css("marginLeft", "152%"); 
}

function toSndTop () {
    $("#rotateRect").removeClass('rotateRectBottom');    
    $("#rotateRect").addClass('rotateRectTop');

    $("#secondRightPart").css("marginLeft", "5%");
    $("#iphoneSecond").css("marginLeft", "52%");

    $("#thirdLeftPart").css("marginLeft", "-105%");
    $("#iphoneThird").css("marginLeft", "152%"); 
}
```

I am pretty lost on this one.
Thank you everyone in advance!
Cheers!

Comment: if you set style `left:0; top:521px` for iframe of video 2 and video 3 - it's OK ...

Comment: Thanks for helping guys. That's really a positioning problem! If I move the iframes to the right position on Safari it will be out of position on Chrome... How do you think I can handle this? Where does this difference come from? Thanks!

Comment: Firefox used to have this wonderful "3d view" of the page, so you could see exactly what's where - unfortunately, they got rid of it a few versions ago - this is only a guess, but I think it's the way you're using margins to move the divs "out of the way" that may be confusing firefox/safari (or they have slightly different layout algorithms) - the problem with CSS is, that some things can be interpreted differently by different browsers and they all think they are correct!! Although, I thought that only happened in the Netscape vs IE days

Comment: as those divs are absolutely positioned, try moving them using left property instead of margin-left (probably a big PITA rewrite though)

Comment: to be honest though, I did a very very rough mockup of your site, and have no such layout oddities

Comment: You probably wrote a better layout. I think I'll have to try some rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the problem.

Firefox used to have this wonderful "3d view" of the page, so you could see exactly what's where - unfortunately, they got rid of it a few versions ago - this is only a guess, but I think it's the way you're using margins to move the divs "out of the way" that may be confusing firefox/safari (or they have slightly different layout algorithms) - the problem with CSS is, that some things can be interpreted differently by different browsers and they all think they are correct!! Although, I thought that only happened in the Netscape vs IE days